# _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI disabled on RHEL6 and RHEL7?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, rhel7, rhel6, devtoolset

I have gcc 5.2.1 on RHEL6 and RHEL7, and it looks like _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI gets disabled. It's not working even if I manually run `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -std=c++14`. This means I won't get small string optimization feature. For example, the output of following code always have 8 and 'micro not set'. For SSO, size of std::string should be at least 16 if we look at code bits/basic_string.h. Any workaround?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(std::string) << std::endl;

#if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
    std::cout << "macro set" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "macro not set" << std::endl;
#endif

}
```

Comment: Define "does not work as expected"? Note that `1` is the default value of that macro.

Comment: Where did you install your GCC from?

Comment: Gcc is firm wide. Presume it's part of RHEL distro?

Comment: [Feature, not a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704).

Comment: You're using the devtoolset version of GCC which doesn't support the new ABI. I'll change the tags on the question to make that clear, since that's the reason for the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[bugzilla.redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704) has below reply

> Jakub Jelinek 2018-02-19 06:08:00 EST
>
> We've tried hard, but it is not possible to support this, neither on
>   RHEL6 nor on RHEL7, which is why it is forcefully disabled.  It will
>   work in RHEL8 (and be the default there as well).

Answer (score -1):

It would depend on your `libstdc++` version, make sure your include/link/runtime paths are correct. Search your system for that macro and then use that instead, just make sure you link against the correct stdlib/abi libs.

If you do not have that, you can always build it yourself, however beware that if the rest of the programs you have use the old ABI, they will not work with your new `libstdc++`.

---

**Edit:** Thinking about this, did you specify the correct `-std=` flag to `g++`? Have you tried `-std=gnu11`? It could be as trivial as that. If not, then read on. Do not manually specify that define, you will break ABI compatibility with your `libstdc++` leading to cascades of wonderful crashes. The only time you can specify things like that are when you're building the stdlib yourself.

---

*Rest of this is a bit overkill, but it explains how to build and/or pick which stdlib you want to use.*

I have a similar problem when using version 2 ABI of `libc++`, where everything that links against it has to be rebuilt with the right headers and thus the right ABI (things like small string optimization being one of them).

For example, when building C++ objects I use the following flags to specify a location to a custom stdlib header path instead of using the OS provided one (I use Clang but the principle is similar):

```
-nostdinc++ -I/usr/local/sdk/llvm.6.0.1/include/c++/v1/
```

And then during the linking phase I use an `$ORIGIN` relative runtime search path since on production machines the standard library is installed in in a more sane location, but you can specify a fixed one to whichever stdlib you want. You also want to make sure the linker can find the appropriate stdlib during static linking with `-L`.

```
-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib' -L/usr/local/sdk/llvm.6.0.1/lib
```

You will need to link against `-lstdc++` and `-lsupc++` (order is important if static linking), as long as you provide the correct library search path, the static linker should find them which are the GCC/GNU C++ stdlib and ABI support library.

**Beware, if you replace your system libstdc+ with this any programs linked against old ABI layout will break if they're dynamically linked so be careful.**

Comment: But my "macro set" code should have nothing to do with libstdc++, right?

Comment: Tried
`g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -std=c++14`
`g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -std=gnu++14`
and with '-D'. Our test prints 'macro not set'.

Comment: Headers (at least on `libc++`) expose ABI details like structure layout, by changing them and building with them you're essentially linking against an incompatible stdlib as it is not header only, it has quite a few compiled parts that expect that layout to be the same. You can build your own stdlib but you'll be breaking ABI compat with every C++ shared object that links against the OS stdlib.

Comment: This answer is fairly misleading. No `-std` option changes the ABI, and the new ABI in libstdc++ did not make all objects and libraries incompatible, that's why the library SONAME didn't change. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html for more details.