# Best practices in updating GCC and boost on RedHat 7.6

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, redhat

My setup: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)`

I was previously having a linking problem when trying to link with a boost static library, which i had found out was caused of it being compiled with the C++17 standard with GCC 8.2 but `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 pointing to libstdc++.so.6.0.19`. GCC 8.2 was installed from `development-toolset8` which I enabled with `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable`. 
Now my question is what is the best practice way to solve this?( i have read quite a lot on this so i have 2 solution below, more like 1 cause the other one is a glimpse of an idea)

**1)** I download the package and do the [installation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html) from here specifying --`enable-shared --prefix=$HOME/gcc` (any other options that you think might be useful? ) Do i need to uninstall the dev-toolset8 for this? Then i recompile the boost package with the flag -`D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1`,

**2)** i try to somehow compile(i have no clue how) the libstdc++.so from the `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libstdc++.a` (How do i do this? no idea?)

Similar description of my problem which seems to be a:[RedHat bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836145/glibcxx-use-cxx11-abi-disabled-on-rhel6-and-rhel7/50839029#50839029)

Thank you

Comment: I can sudjest to not compile boost with yor self, install it from -devel package. And build rpm for your application - with boost package dependecy to redistribute it.

Comment: Rpm search shows boost 1.66 is available for rhel 7.2 and abowe.

Comment: Ok. When I installed it from rpm it just had the .a and.so libraries.i would actually want to compile it with --build-type=complete to show the boost debug libraries as well  Also the rpm one comes with without the c++11 standard. Any thoughts on the gcc installation?